# Maximization of a specific function

Tags: real-analysis

$K\in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $z \in [0,x]\cap [0,K]$ $\gamma>0$ one defines 
\begin{align}
\phi(z)=(K-z)\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)^{\gamma}
\end{align}
The maximum is attained at $z=\frac{\gamma K}{\gamma +1}$.
Question:
Why is for $x\leq \frac{\gamma K}{\gamma +1}$: \begin{align}
\max_{z}\phi(z)=K-x
\end{align}
And for 
$x> \frac{\gamma K}{\gamma +1}$
\begin{align}
\max_{z}\phi(z)=\phi\left(\frac{\gamma K}{\gamma +1}\right) \text{ ?}
\end{align}

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximumis o er $z\in[0,x]\cap[0,K]=[0,\min(x,K)]$. $\phi$ is increasing on $[0,\gamma\,K/(\gamma+1)]$ and decreasing on $[\gamma\,K/(\gamma+1),K]$. If $x\le \gamma\,K/(\gamma+1)$, the maximum is attained precisely at $x$, and its value is $\phi(x)=K-x$. If $x>\gamma\,K/(\gamma+1)$, the maximum is attained at $\gamma\,K/(\gamma+1)$.